# Как получить длительность аудио ( ) до нажатий на play?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Есть тег audio на странице. Можно ли при загрузке страницы получить в js перемену длительность аудио до нажатий на кнопку play. Надо что бы мог вывести как информацию - *Время прослушивания **3 минуты***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следует учесть, что между объявлением элемента аудио и прочтением его свойства duration должно пройти какое-то количество времени, чтобы браузер успел прочитать из файла эту информацию, в противном случае выдаст NaN. Обеспечить успевание можно такими способами:

1) обернуть вывод duration в функцию onloadeddata():
   **audio.onloadeddata = function(){console.log(audio.duration);**

2) просто создать задержку от 200 мс:
   **setTimeout(function(){console.log(audio.duration)},200);**

3) Если между объявлением аудио и выводом duration находится довольно много кода, может оказаться, что на его выполнение уйдёт это необходимое время, и тогда первый или второй пункты не обязательны.

4) Развязка по времени так же произойдёт, если аудио объявить по ходу загрузки страницы, а duration выводить по нажатию на кнопку или по любому другому событию.

Answer (score 1):

Через св-во `duration`, оно доступно даже когда мы еще не начали воспроизведение

```js
const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.onloadeddata = () => {
  console.log(audio.duration)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure>
      <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
      <audio id="audio"
          controls
          src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3">
        Your browser does not support the
        <code>audio</code> element.
      </audio>
    </figure>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ваш код выдал NaN, причину читаем ниже.